# Mobile or PDA on which I can have IDE (integrated development environment) like Visual Studio, Net-beans

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, netbeans, mobile

I just like to code when i travel,but i can't carry my laptop while travelling so i thought of a mobile in which i can create apps in C#, .NET or Java but for that i need an IDE,Compiler,etc.

Basically I am looking for a phone / mobile / PDA (far more handy than a net-book or a laptop) in which i can code the way i can do it normally in Visual Studio installed in a machine.

So are there any such devices ?

Comment: IDE in Mobile Device ? great idea!

Comment: It's impractical.  PDAs are lightweight.  Development environments such as Visual Studio are not.  If you overcame the technical limitations, I think the display-size and input methods would quickly begin to irritate.  This is why, although more unwieldly than a PDA, I code on a decent laptop when I am on the move.  Let PDAs do the job they're designed to do.

Comment: if PDAs are left to do what they do, then they will keep on doing the same old things and will never grow :) !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at what you need to overcome to get this to work.

1) **oomph**

Smart phones are designed to give you the ability to stay in touch, and have a rich experience on the move, but within the confines of a device that can be put in your pocket.  Storage isn't really an issue these days, but processing power on small devices are.  Sure we can run calendar, 3D games (though nowhere near the complexity of what you'll see on a fully-fledged operating system), fart-applications and plug-ins for you-tube so we can watch idiots break their ballsacks on railings, but there's a reason you don't see a fully-fledged rich-desktop application, or Grand Theft Auto IV on these devices.  Oomph.  Now bring in the Visual Studio development environment (and database server, if that is what you're application is doing), with potentially 100s of source files in your language of choice.  Assuming we put a severly cut-down version of your IDE on to your pda, I hope you brought some spare batteries or the power-cord because you're going to need it.

2) **input**

It's probably not difficult to change your predictive text input to cover all the keywords of your chosen language so that you don't end up typing `pubic` instead of `public`.  Once we've solved that we then need to go through the agonizing process of the fact that computer code contains a lot of symbols and identifiers, meaning we'd have to switch our input mode every other word or two to facilitate it:

```
for(int i(0); i < _vector.length(); i++)
```

Takes a few seconds on a keyboard.  Probably about one train journey on your PDA.  To solve this, we must assume the PDA has the facility for an external keyboard to prevent suicide.

3) **display**

Ok, we've solved our oomph problems with a power-chord and/or 50 batteries and we've plugged in our external keyboard.  We're ready to code!!  We'll have to adjust the font-size on the display so that we can get more than 20 lines of code (vertically) or 10 (horizontally).  I enjoy my comfort when I code, so I don't want to be squinting at a small screen as I type on my plug-in keyboard.  I'd have to prop it up against some books or something (so I don't have to hold the PDA *and* the keyboard).  Now I can't see what i am doing.  So, I need a bigger display.

4) **Target code**

What platform are you targeting?  Remember the PDA is designed to run software for the PDA in question.  You won't be able to write fully-fledged win32 applications on Windows Mobile 7.  There are differences in the API.  What if it's a web app you're developing?  We're going to have to add a web server to the phone too, unless that is deployed elsewhere and we can rely on an internet connection to upload the changed files to.

Have we solved the problem?  Did we get more oomph?  A keyboard?  A bigger display?  Yes we did.

**It's a laptop**.

Comment: laptop is awesome but i am still in search of a PDA or a mobile like device.Thanks for your input on "why we can't have a such mobile?" but i would be looking for "how we can have such mobile device".It may not entirely support all functions of a Modern IDE but atleast to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

It's impractical, as Moo-Juice mentioned. However, you could try using online compilers that work through web browsers, such as [Compilr.com](http://compilr.com). Perhaps this could work well enough through a mobile device's web browser. This way you could write snippets of code and verify that it compiles. Otherwise, you'll be stuck getting a netbook or laptop.

Comment: No alternatives please.Such web sites in which you have an IDE, work very slow and I have tried  Compilr.com its really very slow.I would prefer an app installed in my device rather than going online for an IDE.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [VNC client](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/) or [Remote Desktop client](http://mochasoft.dk/iphone_rdp.htm) or something.

Obviously your experience will not be very good on a phone/PDA, but I also don't have an IDE installed on my laptop -- I just use remote desktop (and a wireless modem if I'm desperately bored and can't find wifi).

Comment: This would be my suggestion. Get something on an Android or iPhone that lets you connect to a "real" computer.

Comment: Wow! thats good idea.I would definitely try it out and I hope it works on Windows Phone.But, still looking for any IDE installed on windows phone which could be more better than remotely accessing another PC. After all this is a good alternative.

Comment: You'd be surprised how good Remote Desktop performance is, even over a 3G connection. It's pretty seamless. Besides, I'm pretty sure you'll never find as good an IDE as Visual Studio/Eclipse/whatever on a phone.

Comment: Thanks may be your right,i wish i had such an IDE on Mobile as well.